# Why does Browserify try to convert the next piece of code after the bundle into a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

My gulp file concats the browserify bundle with some other code. When this happens the code that appears directly after the bundle always gives the error "Cannot find module" and then a lot of code. Is this supposed to happen? Also, the error is coming from node_modules/browserify/nod_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1. Can you please help me make browserify not try t convert the code after the bundle. Or is this not possible and I should load the code separately in the HTML.

Comment: Did you try copy > pasting your separate piece of JS code manually below the code that browserify generated? Perhaps gulp is not correctly concatenating the two files.

Comment: @Kokodoko I just tried that and the error message was the same.

Comment: Perhaps your watch settings notice a change and then do some operation on your code. You should have a watched source folder and a destination folder. Changes in the destination folder should not trigger a new build process.